# $scope.slider - not updated

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, angular-ui

I have a jquery-ui slider which updates a textbox with the slider's value.

the textbox has ng-model so I can get the value from the controller - but the value is not updated after the slider is moved  (the value is changing inside the textbox visually, but $scope.slider remains the same).

If I change the value manually inside the textbox everything is working as expected and the value of $scope.slider is updated with the new value.

Is there a way to make the slider update the value for the scope as well?

```
   <input type="text" id="rent"  ng-model="rent" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
  <div id="slider-rent" style="width: 80%;"></div>

  $("#slider-rent").slider({
        range: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 20000,
        step: 10,
        value: 0,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#rent").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#rent").val($("#slider-rent").slider("value"));
    $("#rent").change(function () {

        $("#slider-rent").slider("value", $("#rent").val());
    });
```

(This is a rtl slider, this is why the values are negative)

Comment: where's your code? It is anyone's guess how you are managing the slider update and how it is integrated with angular....likely need to trigger change event on the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to put your slider code into an angular directive so you can access the controller scope.

However if you trigger `input event` on the `input element` it will update the angular `model`

```
function updateInputValue( newVal){
     $("#rent").val(newVal).trigger('input');    
}

$(function () {
    $("#slider-rent").slider({
        range: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 20000,
        step: 10,
        value: 0,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            updateInputValue(ui.value);
        }
    });
    updateInputValue($("#slider-rent").slider("value"));
    $("#rent").change(function () {
        $("#slider-rent").slider("value", $("#rent").val());
    });
})
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/zwHQs/

Comment: @MarkRajcok was easier than trying to teach how to build a directive and access scope

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
    $scope.rent = ui.value;

}
```

The above assumes the code you show is inside/wrapped in a directive.